# Unity : Rotate object on touch looks weird

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

Touch and hold the screen then rotate object continue(`"Object is unity default cube"`)  that's my operation, but when object is Rotate then it's look like weird.

[image][image]

I upload the example for better understand, it's looks like above image.

```
public void StartHold()
{
    pointerDown = true;
}
public void StopHold()
{
    pointerDown = false;
}
void Update()
{
  if(pointerDown){
    Rotator.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 90) * 2f * Time.deltaTime);
  }
}
```

It's just simple way to rotate object not to much complication then why object rotation look like this, anyone can know then help me and what is the solution of this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps rephrase the question. It's not really clear what you're trying to do, or what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i just do object rotation start when long press, and when release rotation stop that's it and it is done there's no issue in rotation but when object rotate it's look like example screenshot look at the edge of object not clean.